# Is there a way to read .meta files from Dota 2 replays?

Tags: dota-2

I've been really interested to see what these .meta files contain. They're generated alongside replay files (.dem files) from Steam, so I'm really curious if there's a known way to view their contents.

Comment: If someone downvotes my question, could you please at least explain why? I don't know where would be a better place to ask something like this.

Comment: I don't know what .meta files are but I assume they are not limited to gaming. Also reading these files does not pertain to playing games so not really on-topic here. I haven't voted but I thought I'd give some outside perspective.

Comment: @VanBuzzKill Thanks for the input. I thought it'd be more relevant here instead of Game Development since it's more related to the game itself and not the development of it. I guess I'll look elsewhere then, thanks!

Comment: Meta files in general (and I don't see why Dota 2's metas would be any different) contain information about the file itself and its contents. My guess wold be a timestamp, stats from the game (kills, wins etc.), names of the players/team, a hash sum for the file etc. Metas are often used for easily indexing data. For example in this case if you are looking for a specific team and the games it has participated in in the last week the info inside the meta allows the search engine to locate and sort accordingly the results.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a know way to read their content using the [clarity replay parser](https://github.com/skadistats/clarity).

Especially this example :

https://github.com/skadistats/clarity-examples/tree/master/src/main/java/skadistats/clarity/examples/metadata

The file contains various information used by the game to display post game stats. Like graph data, item purchase time, ...